# Referencing custom elements in DocBook

Tags: xslt, docbook

another weekend and time to further play around with DocBook :-)

I added custom elements to my DocBook document and am translating them to FO and then to PDF via a XSLT transformation. This all works pretty fine. For example, I'm having a custom chapter element like:

```
<MyChapter xml:id="mychapter">
<title>Test</title>
</MyChapter
```

The background is that I want to enforce certain structures in that document and that basically works very well. There is only one thing that does not work and that I'm stuck with. My custom elements cannot be the target of an xref. E.g. the following does not work:

```
<xref linkend="mychapter"/>
```

While I think that I understand the reason that it is not working, I'm completely lost in fixing this. Did anybody here do anything similiar before and could give me a hint on how to approach this?

EDIT:

Following the first answer, I looked into what happens if (standard) sect3 is referenced. This seems to be controlled by the following template in this [file](https://github.com/docbook/xslt10-stylesheets/blob/master/xsl/html/xref.xsl#L340):

```
<xsl:template match="d:section|d:simplesect
                     |d:sect1|d:sect2|d:sect3|d:sect4|d:sect5
                     |d:refsect1|d:refsect2|d:refsect3|d:refsection" mode="xref-to">
  <xsl:param name="referrer"/>
  <xsl:param name="xrefstyle"/>
  <xsl:param name="verbose" select="1"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="object.xref.markup">
    <xsl:with-param name="purpose" select="'xref'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="xrefstyle" select="$xrefstyle"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="referrer" select="$referrer"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="verbose" select="$verbose"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  <!-- FIXME: What about "in Chapter X"? -->
</xsl:template>
```

I'm trying to follow the logic here but I get stucked at

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="object.xref.markup">
```

What does this line do?

Comment: `xml:id` is not something specific to  DocBook or XSLT. Also you have not explained what exactly happens for "does not work", do you get any errors, if so which one, in which context (XML validation, XSLT stylesheet execution). And for DocBook and XSLT it helps if you exactly explain which versions you are working with.

Comment: The document is processed but in the resulting PDF the reference is resolved as "???". I'm using DocBook version 5.

Comment: And which XSLT version of the DocBook stylesheets?

Comment: https://github.com/docbook/xslt10-stylesheets

Comment: Shouldn't the attribute on the `xref` element not be called `linkend` instead of `linked`?

Comment: I corrected the linkend attribute in the post. However, this has not been the issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166157/discussion-between-martin-honnen-and-norbert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually DocBook xref referencing logic is quite straightforward. If someone try to illustrate this logic by using human words it would be something like: put the link to the `object1` with `xml:id1` (using `linkend`) and get generated text from `object2`  with `xml:id2` (using `endterm`) as link text.

So, I suggest you want to put the mychapter title as a reference text. I would be change your sample as follows:

```
<MyChapter xml:id="mychapter">
<title xml:id="mychapter_title">Test</title>
</MyChapter>
```

Link snippet:

```
<xref linkend="mychapter" endterm="mychapter_title"/>
```

You'll get the reference (link itself) to your chapter with a reference text (link text) from a chapter title.

This schema certainly works with default elements and should work with your custom elements if you use the default xsl template adopted to your custom `mychapter`.

This logic is described very well here: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CrossRefs.html

Comment: That works great! Thanks for pointing me into this direction. I'm wondering whether it will also be possible that those links are shown as hyperlinks in the PDF document so that the user can click on them. Any idea on this as well?

Comment: @Norbert, Please, refine your question. There are differences between: ref WITHIN the document, ref BEYOND the document, and even hyperlinks itself (uris) that concatenated to the refs text itself to provide offline user of any print document use it without a computer (i.e. manually print the url in address bar later).

Comment: Fixing TYPO: i.e. manually **type** the url in browser address bar later.

Comment: Sorry for being so imprecise. In this case the ref to my custom elements ends WITHIN in the same document.

Comment: @norbert, it works out of box for default xrefs. **NOTE**: if xref target is on the same page (i.e. xref source and xref target on the same page) - it looks like nothing happened. But it is just **feeling** because pdf viewer doesn't move to any other page after clicking xref.

Comment: Indeed, I checked the FO-file and it seems that the refs are actually embedded as links. Unfortunately. they don't work in the PDF (tested with multiple viewers, link is on a different page). I will have to look into this issue in more detail but this does not seem to have to do with the XSL transformation.

Comment: @norbet, Some ideas, what can be done further. If this is not xsl issue it can be possible tha FO-processor (FOP, XEP, Antenna Formatter) interpreted fo file in a different way. Try to generate PDF with different FO-processors - not only view in different viewers. While doing so, don't forget about special xsl, that related to special fo processor - see fop1.xsl, xep.xsl, axf.xsl respectively in DocBook XSL Stylesheets and turn them on with appropriate param in param.xsl (i.e. fop1.extensions = 1)

Comment: Thanks. I will consider these details.